# WCF ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher error

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf-data-services

Need help guys! We have existing old system ASP.NET with WCF and Microsoft enterprise library and I'm new in WCF. They have a system generated Service Model    like this

Interface System generated:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "IMyService")]
public interface IMyService
```

Class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public partial class MyService : IMyService
```

Then they asked me to add a method under interface and class like this

Added method in interface:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute (Action = "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/DoWork", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IMyService /DoWorkReponse")]
void DoWork (int param1,int param2);

public void DoWork (int param1,int param2)
{
   base.Channel.DoWork (int param1,int param2);
}
```

Added method in class:

```
Public void DoWork(int param1,int param2)
```

And then when I’m trying to call the method like this:

```
IMyService.DoWork(1,2)
```

It shows like this:

**System.ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException: 'The message with Action ‘http://tempuri.org/IMyService/DoWork ' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).'**

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't know whether it is your problem , but when I pasted your ReplyAction , I found there is  a space   between the last /   and IMyService ,  in http://tempuri.org/IMyService /DoWorkReponse

Answer (score 0):

Today I ended up with the same error and doing below workaround solved issue for me.

At client-side application, Removing existing WCF service reference and adding it again solved the issue for me.

However, first, you may also need to verify that the hosting application service contract address and client endpoint address contract are the same.

i.e. *Host configuration.*

[image: WCF service]

*Client configuration*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created new service by copying existing one and forgot to rename 'Service' attribute in this .svc file.

I received following error:
System.ServiceModel.ActionNotSupportedException: The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/...' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Issue was resolved once I set 'Service' attribute correctly.